# How to use $contexts in Page Manager

Tags: 7, chaos-tool-suite

Im trying to make a selection rule for variants in Page manger and it includes some data comparison so it has to be in php. My field data is inside the context, so the `$contexts` variable can be used, but I cant get the proper way to use it. In my case it is a field value of the node, that is specified by the argument in URL "node/%nid".

Can some body please give an example code to extract the field value from context in php?

Comment: In my case [this code](http://drupal.org/node/1212198) became suitable solution `$value = ctools_context_keyword_substitute('%node:field-proj-status', array(), $contexts)`

Comment: The code above will work but it'll also give you Watchdog errors as per http://drupal.org/node/1781086

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I want to point out that since [this issue](http://drupal.org/node/1300476) got closed in December, ctools got much better support for handling fields in access rules.

With that said, `$contexts`, have a data value, which is either an object, or an array of objects, depending on whether your plugin requires one or more contexts.

To make the code easier to read, I usually do something like this: `$node = $context->data;`

Brief example code:

```
function contact_info_pane_content_type_render($subtype, $conf, $args, $context = NULL) {
  $block = new stdClass;
  $block->content = '';
  $node = $context->data;
  $block->content .= count($node->field_email) > 0) ? $node->field_event_mail['und'][0]['email'] : '';
  $block->content .= count($node->field_phonenumber) > 0) ? $node->field_event_phonenumber['und'][0]['safe_value'] : '';

  return $block;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

panels php https://drupal.org/sandbox/rogical/2121111

This module would solve this issue

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.